# STM32 & FreeRTOS task scheduling

Tags: task, stm32, scheduling, freertos, stm32f4

I need to run three tasks in order of priority

```
/* Definitions for myTask01 */
osThreadId_t myTask01Handle;
const osThreadAttr_t myTask01_attributes = {
  .name = "myTask01",
  .stack_size = 512 * 4,
  .priority = (osPriority_t) osPriorityLow,
};
/* Definitions for myTask02 */
osThreadId_t myTask02Handle;
const osThreadAttr_t myTask02_attributes = {
  .name = "myTask02",
  .stack_size = 512 * 4,
  .priority = (osPriority_t) osPriorityNormal,
};
/* Definitions for myTask03 */
osThreadId_t myTask03Handle;
const osThreadAttr_t myTask03_attributes = {
  .name = "myTask03",
  .stack_size = 512 * 4,
  .priority = (osPriority_t) osPriorityHigh,
};
```

The tasks simply blink the PA5 led

```
void StartTask02(void *argument) //Normal priority
{
      for(;;)
      {
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5);
        osDelay(2000);
      }
      osThreadTerminate(NULL);
}
```

Of course, in the main, the tasks are created and the scheduler is initialized and started.

When I run the firmware, only the third task run (it has a faster blinking).

If I put this for in the third task

```
void StartTask03(void *argument) //High priority
{
      for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
      {
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5);
        osDelay(100);
      }
      osThreadTerminate(NULL);
}
```

it blinks when is in for loop, and when it exits from the for loop, the led stops blinking.

How can I run the other tasks? Thanks

Comment: You’re toggling the same pin/LED in both tasks. This might be confusing. Also you should verify that HAL_GPIO_TogglePin is thread safe i.e. can be used from multiple tasks at the same time. Otherwise you need a (mutex or critical section) protection for this call (accessing the shared HW resource GPIOA).

Comment: You can try changing the task priority, there are 7 stages to each priority level like osPriorityNormal1, osPriorityNormal2, etc. Try making them of the same priority level with different stages. Also the LED will stop blinking if Task3 has exited or are you referring to Task 2 controlling the same LED.